# Repeatable insert of row into table in Oracle SQL

Tags: sql, oracle, sequence

I want to have a script that can be run several times, without adding a row to the database state after the first time. It should insert a row with two columns into KPI_TYPE table, the columns being KPI_TYPE_ID and NAME, and it would be nice if it updated the sequence KPI_TYPE_SEQ, but only on the first run.

What I got as a first idea is this:

```
merge into KPI_TYPE dest
using (select 26 as KPI_TYPE_ID, 'Web Service Availability' as NAME from dual) src
on (src.KPI_TYPE_ID = dest.KPI_TYPE_ID)
when matched then update set 
  dest.NAME    = src.NAME
when not matched then 
  insert (KPI_TYPE_ID, NAME)
  values (src.KPI_TYPE_ID, src.NAME);
```

This achieves almost what I want, but it doesn't update the sequence. It would also be nice if the update of the sequence only happened if the value was 26. It would be ok if it happened in a second SQL command.

There is also a trigger attaching the sequence to the table:

```
create or replace TRIGGER "SCHEMA"."B1_KPI_TYPE" 
  BEFORE INSERT ON KPI_TYPE
  FOR EACH ROW
DECLARE
BEGIN
  IF( :new.KPI_TYPE_ID IS NULL )
  THEN
    :new.KPI_TYPE_ID := KPI_TYPE_SEQ.nextval;
  END IF;
END;
```

Example data before:

```
11  DB Connectivity
12  DB Health Check
13  SOAP Service Availability
14  FTP/SFTP Server Availability
18  Queue Check
19  Business Check
20  Engine Availability
21  Backlog Management
23  Composite KPI
24  DB Objects Check
25  SMSC Gateway Availability
```

Sequence before:

```
CREATED 01.06.18
LAST_DDL_TIME   01.06.18
SEQUENCE_OWNER  SCHEMA
SEQUENCE_NAME   KPI_TYPE_SEQ
MIN_VALUE   1
MAX_VALUE   9999999999999999999999999999
INCREMENT_BY    1
CYCLE_FLAG  N
ORDER_FLAG  N
CACHE_SIZE  0
LAST_NUMBER 26
```

After first time the script ran:

```
11  DB Connectivity
12  DB Health Check
13  SOAP Service Availability
14  FTP/SFTP Server Availability
18  Queue Check
19  Business Check
20  Engine Availability
21  Backlog Management
23  Composite KPI
24  DB Objects Check
25  SMSC Gateway Availability
26  Web Service Availability
```

Sequence after the first run:

```
CREATED 01.06.18
LAST_DDL_TIME   01.06.18
SEQUENCE_OWNER  SCHEMA
SEQUENCE_NAME   KPI_TYPE_SEQ
MIN_VALUE   1
MAX_VALUE   9999999999999999999999999999
INCREMENT_BY    1
CYCLE_FLAG  N
ORDER_FLAG  N
CACHE_SIZE  0
LAST_NUMBER 27
```

After second time the script ran:

```
11  DB Connectivity
12  DB Health Check
13  SOAP Service Availability
14  FTP/SFTP Server Availability
18  Queue Check
19  Business Check
20  Engine Availability
21  Backlog Management
23  Composite KPI
24  DB Objects Check
25  SMSC Gateway Availability
26  Web Service Availability (It is also ok if this gets updated to 26 New Name)
```

Sequence after the second run:

```
CREATED 01.06.18
LAST_DDL_TIME   01.06.18
SEQUENCE_OWNER  SCHEMA
SEQUENCE_NAME   KPI_TYPE_SEQ
MIN_VALUE   1
MAX_VALUE   9999999999999999999999999999
INCREMENT_BY    1
CYCLE_FLAG  N
ORDER_FLAG  N
CACHE_SIZE  0
LAST_NUMBER 27
```

I'm trying this now:

```
declare v_seqvariable number;
begin
    SELECT last_number INTO v_seqvariable 
      FROM all_sequences
     WHERE sequence_owner = 'SCHEMA'
       AND sequence_name = 'KPI_TYPE_SEQ';    

    if v_seqvariable = 26 then DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line('Is 26'); else DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line('Is not 26'); end if;
end;
```

However, I don't get any output. Do I have to flush it or something?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean. You update tables and columns, not sequences. What is *'adding a row to the database state'*?

Comment: By updating the sequence I mean calling `sequence.nextval`. However it should only be called when the current value of the sequence is `26`. The database state is having 10 rows in a table and adding an 11th row, but it should not add more rows if the script is called several times.

Comment: Can you explain a little more about the sequence, how and why do you want it updated?

Comment: Something like `select kpi_type_seq.nextval from dual`? What does that have to do with the table you are updating? Why does it matter what its current value is?

Comment: The table has a trigger for inserting row having a KPI_TYPE_ID of null, then it will use the `nextval` from the sequence. But if the script is run twice I don't want to have another row and I don't want `seq.nextval` to increase the sequence. I also don't want to increase the sequence if it return for example a value other than 26

Comment: Some example data would really help clarify your question. So if KPI_TYPE_ID is 26 and the row doesn't exist, you want to insert and increment the sequence; if the ID is 26 and the row does exist, you want to update and not increment the sequence; and if the ID is not 26, you want to do nothing?

Comment: I inserted example data in the question.

Comment: I expect something like `if kpi_type_seq.last_number = 26 then select kpi_type_seq.nextval from dual;` would do the trick, but I am unsure how to actually write that code.

Answer (score 0):

The following code does to the sequence what I want:

```
SET SERVEROUTPUT ON;
declare 
v_seqvariable number;
v_result number;
begin
    SELECT last_number INTO v_seqvariable 
      FROM all_sequences
     WHERE sequence_owner = 'SCHEMA'
       AND sequence_name = 'KPI_TYPE_SEQ';    

    if v_seqvariable = 26 then DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line('Is 26'); select SCHEMA.KPI_TYPE_SEQ.nextval INTO v_result FROM DUAL; else DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line('Is not 26'); end if;
end;
```

Output is:

```
anonymer Block abgeschlossen
Is 26

anonymer Block abgeschlossen
Is not 26
```

Now what is left is that I only have to test the MERGE code.